# Page alignment after window resize

Tags: html, css

When ever I develop HTML pages, I get problem with window resize. The page alignment gets disturbed. One element or tag overlaps with the other.I want my page that when I resize,
my page it should remain the same & srollbars should appear.Someone Pls suggest solution.Which style attribute (position, overflow)  is good to use for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a `width` on the body (or, more preferably, a `min-width`)

Comment: Hi all, The window UI should remain unchanged(ok, for slight contraction in width & height of elements like decrease in padding or margin b/w them), but the layout should be almost intact as before (as with full width,height),should look as intended to & we can see that one being intact by sliding scroll bars even after the window is reduced to it's smallest size. This is the most commonly followed strategy of window resize for almost all webpages.How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you need, but probably:

```
overflow:auto;
```

is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

i understand i think, the issue is that you place your elements in a relative position(the default for position on any element), so relative to your current screen size. you can change the position to absolute and they will not move, this can cause you to loose control if your not an css ninja. ill show some cool techniques now how to control elements.

hint 1:
wrap your tags! a wrapped element will stay put!
example:

html =>

```
<div id="box_wrapper">
  <div class="box">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
  </div>
  <div class="box">
  </div>
</div>
```

css =>

```
#box_wrapper {
  margin: /*top and bottom*/5px /*left and right*/ auto; /*this will center your wrapper*/
  height: 300px; /*what ever height you want*/
  width: 1200px; /*what ever width you want*/
 }
.box {
  /*what dimensions you want*/
 }
```

this a good way of keeping objects in place, they will never leave the wrapper element if you specify a overflow.

hint 2:
position: absolute; caution this can get messy.

i use position absolute when positioning logos to the corner of a screen so that if you change the size of the screen the logo will still remain in the corner. this is cool cause you dont need a specified width for the parent elements.

html

```
<div class="header">
 <img src="/images/logo.png" alt="page_logo">
 <div id="login_button">
   /*......*/
 </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.header {
  width: 100%
  height: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
}
.header img{
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0px; /*position: absolute must have a margin even if its 0*/
  float: left;
  height: 150px;
}
#login_buttons {
 float:left;
 position: absolute right;
 margin-right: 5px;
}
```

this example puts a logo on the top left hand side and the login buttons on the right and if you then change the screen size it will keep them where they need to be.

i dont want to write a whole tutorial here but these tips should help in designing solid pages that adapt to multiple screen sizes.
its hard to kinda guess what the issue could be if i cant see the code but i hope this helps.

Comment: Is there a way that window UI remains unchanged as like full width,height & we can see that original one being intact by sliding scroll bars even the window is reduced to it's smallest size. This is the solution followed for window resize as I observed with most of webpages.How to achieve this?

Comment: in the body tag add overflow: auto;

Answer (score 0):

```
<body id="page" onload=" pageHeight = document.getElementById('page').offsetHeight;
 pageWidth = document.getElementById('page').offsetWidth;

pageHeight=1000 px ;
pageWidth=600 px ;
"> </body>
```

*you got to fix the width of the body on page load to pixels instead of % based on the resized browser window size.*